# How Remove EPS-preview?

Tags: eps, preview, journal-publishing, journal, tiff

How to tell if a particular EPS figure has a TIFF preview and how to remove this preview?

For some reason the Journal of Mathematical Physics don't want these preview to be there when uploading files.

Comment: On Linux, the ps2eps(1) command has an option to remove the preview from an EPS file.

Comment: Is this question # 90000? (:-)

Comment: It seems that a preview can be represented in different ways. You could take a look into an EPS file with an editor to see how it is represented. Please report back. If it is represented between `%%BeginPreview` and `%%EndPreview`, a simple sed script could remove it. Please also tell us about the operating system you are on.

Comment: Hi, the system is Macbook Yosemite 10.10.3 TeXShop 3.51

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I don't know man?